# How to let a column span multiple rows using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to transform the above mock-up into **HTML** and **CSS** but struggling to make it work by making the image span through **2 rows**.

I have tried making it possible through some code I found online but it is still not looking responsive.

This what I have done so far.

[image]

Here is my code:

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  grid-gap: 1px;
  /*background-color: #2196F3;*/ 

}
.grid-container > div {
  /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);*/ 
  /*text-align: center;*/ 

  font-size: 25px;
}

.fa {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.fa-google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.fa-youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="grid-container">
  <!--div class="item1">Header</div-->
  <div class="item2" style="width: 10px"><img src="" ></div>
  <div class="item3" style="margin-left: 80px;">

  <p style="font-size: 15px; margin-top: 3px">LAWAL HARDCORE <br> 

  UI/UX | Graphics Designer. </p>

<div style="font-size: 15px;"> Email: Lawal@eventor.com </div>   

  </div>


  <!--div class="item4">Right</div-->
  <div class="item5" style="background-color:#4f2684; margin-right: 100px; margin-left: 80px; color: white; width: 600px;">

  <div style="font-size: 18px"> Cranium One, Towry Close, Victoria Island, Lagos. 

<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a> 
 </div> 

  <div style="font-size: 18px"> 08023444444 | info@eventor.com | www.eventor.com </div> 

  </div>
</div>

<div> disclaimers: This email and any files transmitted with it are confidential and intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they are addressed. This message contains confidential information and is intended only for the individual named. If you are not the named addressee you should not disseminate, distribute or copy this e-mail. Please notify the sender immediately by e-mail if you have received this e-mail by mistake and delete this e-mail from your system.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please can someone guide me through? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use simple flexbox? 
First row = image + div wrap with text (on the right of the photo) 
second row= disclaimer 100% width.

Inside div with text (the one next to the photo)  you shouldn't have troubles positioning elements, just use h and p tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
  [image]
[jsfiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/jff71sxk/)

```
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender; margin: 0px;">


    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/b9/Terminator-2-judgement-day.jpg/250px-Terminator-2-judgement-day.jpg" width="250" height="250">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:white;">
            <h1 style="color:#512586;">LAWAL HARDCORE</h1>
            <h3 style="color:#;">UI/UX  Designer | Graphics Designer</h3>
            <p> <b>EMAIL:</b> lawalhardcore@eventor.com</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:#512586; color: white; height: 120px;">
            <div class="cols-12">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h4>Craninum One, Towry Close,</h4>

                <h4>Adeola  Odeku,  Victoria Island, Lagos.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 25px; height: 68px; text-align: center;">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 50%;">
                    <span class="fa fa-facebook" style="color: #512586"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 50%;">
                    <span class="fa fa-twitter" style="color: #512586"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 50%;">
                    <span class="fa fa-instagram" style="color: #512586"></span>
                  </button>

                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 50%;">
                    <span class="fa fa-linkedin" style="color: #512586"></span>
                  </button>
            </div>


            </div>
            <div class="cols-12" >
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            <p>08111 0832 161</p>
            </div>  
            <span class="col-sm-1">|</span>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            <p>info@eventor.com</p> 
            </div> 
            <span class="col-sm-1">|</span>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            <p>www.eventor.com</p>
            </div> 

        </div>

    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:white;">
        <div> DISCLAIMER: This email and any files transmitted with it are confidential and intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they are addressed. This message contains confidential information and is intended only for the individual named. If you are not the named addressee you should not disseminate, distribute or copy this e-mail. Please notify the sender immediately by e-mail if you have received this e-mail by mistake and delete this e-mail from your system.</div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```